# Django doesn't check passwords when reset

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-authentication

I'm using Django's password_reset forms with overriden html files, and when I pushed my code to my server, I could suddenly make the password 1 character long, where they should at least be 8 characters long. BUT it does show an alert if password1 and password2 aren't identical

**On my local machine the Django project was created using 1.11.3, and on the server the Django project was created in version 1.8.7.**
The form I use for posting the new password:

```
    <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
       <input name="new_password1" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Adgangskode">                                                 

       {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
            <strong>{{ value|escape }}</strong>                    
       {% endfor %}

       <input name="new_password2" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Bekræft adgangskode">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="Bekræft">
    </form>
```

*The question is: why does Django not properly validate the password (checking if it's are entirely numeric, or if it's longer than 8 characters), on the server, but perfectly on my local machine?*

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason to use different Django versions between dev and prod. Install the same one on each.

Comment: (Also, displaying the template is pointless; we'd need to see the view and form.)